# Grep a filename with a specific underscore pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, redhat

I am trying to grep a pattern from files using egrep and regex without success.

What I need is to get a file with for example a convention name of:

```
xx_code_lastname_firstname_city.doc
```

The code should have at least 3 digits, the lastname and firstname and city can vary on size

I am trying the code below but it fails to achieve what I desire:

```
ls -1  | grep -E "[xx_][A-Za-z]{3,}[_][A-Za-z]{2,}[_][A-Za-z]{2,}[_][A-Za-z]{2,}[.][doc|pdf]"
```

That is trying to get the standard xx_ from the beggining, then any code that has at least 3 words and after that it must have another underscore, and so on.
Could anybody help ?

Comment: Don't use `ls | grep` -- see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Can you specify which shell you're using? Red Hat ships several -- bash? mksh?

Comment: BTW, `[xx_]` matches *one* character, either an `x` or a `_`.

Comment: You seem to have some confusion around character classes and literal strings.  For instance, if you're looking for `xx_` don't use `[xx_]` because the latter specifies a character class which will match exactly one character which is `x` or `_`

Comment: When you say that the code should have at least 3 digits, do you mean numbers? Because in your regex I see you're using `[a-zA-Z]{3,}`... so what do you mean by digits?

Comment: @wcarroll: I think he means 3 characters

Comment: If you're using Bash you can (and should) use extended globs: `shopt -s extglob nullglob` and then: `printf '%s\n' xx_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]])_+([[:alpha:]])_+([[:alpha:]])_+([[:alpha:]]).@(doc|pdf)`.

Comment: @wcarroll I mean 3 chars.

Comment: @Charles Duffy bash

Comment: @Mensch, please tag for bash, then; "shell" is a much more generic tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider an extglob, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob # turn on extended globbing syntax

files=( xx_[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])_[[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])_[[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])_[[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]]).@(doc|docx|pdf) )

[[ -e ${files[0]} ]] || -L ${files[0]} ]] && printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

---

This works because

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])
```

...matches any string of three or more alpha characters -- two of them explicitly, one of them with the `+()` one-or-more extglob syntax.

---

Similarly,

```
@(doc|docx|pdf)
```

...matches any of these three specific strings.

Comment: Just use `nullglob`, ditch the ugly `[[ -e || -L ]]` trick, and you'll have what I suggested in the comment `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I'm a little wary of `nullglob` unless we direct the OP to turn it back off immediately after -- it's easy to get into traps with commands that have a default behavior if given no arguments, being why nullglob is off-by-default to start with.

Comment: Then use `failglob`. But either is highly recommended when using globs.

Answer (score 3):

So you're trying to match a literal `xx_`? Begin your pattern with that portion then.

```
xx_
```

Next comes the "3 digits" you're trying to match. I'm going to assume based off your own regex that by "digits" you mean characters (hence the `[a-zA-Z]` character classes). Let's make the quantifier non-greedy to avoid any unintentional capturing behavior.

```
xx_[a-zA-Z]{3,}?
```

For the firstname and lastname portions, I see you've specified a variable length with at least 2 characters. Let's make sure these quantifiers are non-greedy as well by appending the `?` character after our quantifiers. According to your regex, it also looks like you expect your city construct to take a similar form to the firstname and lastname bits. Let's add all three then.

```
xx_[a-zA-Z]{3,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.
```

NOTE: We didn't need to make the city quantifier non-greedy since we asserted that it's followed by a literal `"."`, which we don't expect to appear anywhere else in the text we're interested in matching. Notice how it's escaped because it's a metacharacter in the regex syntax.

Lastly comes the file extensions, which your example has as `"docx"`. I also see you put a `"doc"` and a `"pdf"` extension in your regex. Let's combine all three of these.

```
xx_[a-zA-Z]{3,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}?_[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.(docx?|pdf)
```

Hopefully this works. Comment if you need any clarification. Notice how the `"doc"` and the `"docx"` portions were condensed into one element. This is not necessary, but I think it looks more deliberate in this form. It could also be written as `(doc|docx|pdf)`. A little repetitive for my taste.

Comment: `\w` is not supported by `grep -E`, with uses POSIX ERE syntax, without PCRE extensions. (Some versions of GNU grep support `grep -P` if compiled with libpcre support, but that's very much an optional compile-time extension).

Comment: Good catch. I'll use the specific character classes then. I always use PCREs... helps me maintain my sanity.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `[[:alpha:]]` in preference to `[a-zA-Z]` -- sure, if you're in the `C` locale there's no difference, but we have readers in other parts of the world, with different alphabets. :)

Comment: This is almost what I need, I've tested your code and what I get is more than I wanted. For example: if I have a file with more "_" than what I want I still get the entire file and not exactly what I need. In this case I get xx_ln_fn_city_local_postal.docx, but I need files exactly till city - xx_ln_fn_city.docx

Comment: @Mensch There is no mention of this in your question. Your question seems to be missing some key parts that would really clarify what you're trying to accomplish. Also, in `xx_ln_fn_city_local_postal.docx`, there is no "code". Are you saying that you want it to match things like `xx_ln_fn_city_local_postal.docx` and `xx_ln_fn_city.docx`. It would be helpful if you'd edit your original question and add examples of multiple filenames that you are trying to match and multiple filenames that you would not like to match.

Comment: @wcarroll Sry for that, but I've used your code with /w instead of a-zA-Z and it did the trick and tried Charles one, that worked too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mensch, out of curiosity, which `grep` implementation, and were you using `-P`? The POSIX ERE spec is pretty explicit about what it does and doesn't support -- see  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html and, for the grep side, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html [explicitly indicating that ERE is the syntax that should be used with `-E`, and BRE without] -- but I'm wondering if you have an OS vendor that extends it even under `-E`.

Comment: Hmm. Actually... the `?`s following `{2,}` or similar are to make the matches non-greedy? I want to say that's a PCRE extension as well. Does it have any actual effect on what will or won't be matched in this case?